# Object doesn't support property or method $('#myGantt').gantt({

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a gantt chart from existing code. When I run it I get an error. `$('#myGantt').gantt({`. All the dependencies are installed and linked correct.

```
<div id="myGantt"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myTask = [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Task 1',
        title: 'Title 1',
        date_start: '2019-05-09',
        date_end: '2019-06-10',
        color: '#ADFF2F',
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Task 2',
        date_start: '2019-06-15',
        date_end: '2019-06-20',
        color: '#ADD8E6',
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Task 3',
        date_start: '2019-07-05',
        date_end: '2019-07-15',
        color: '#FFDAB9',
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Task 4',
        date_start: '2019-07-16',
        date_end: '2019-07-18',
        color: '#BC8F8F',
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: 'Task 5',
        date_start: '2019-07-20',
        date_end: '2019-07-23',
        color: '#9932CC'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Task 6',
        date_start: '2019-07-25',
        date_end: '2019-07-28',
        color: '#808000'
    }
];

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  dtStart: '2019-05-05',
  dtEnd: '2019-09-05' 
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  width: 500, // default auto
  height: 400
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  click: function(taskId, taskName, taskCountDays){ 
    console.log('task', taskId, taskName, taskCountDays);
  }
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  locale: 'pt-BR'
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  labelTask: true
});

$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask,
  widthCorrectionFirstCol: 100
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are repeatedly applying gantt() function to same DOM element $('#myGantt') with different input params. You should collect all Params and call gantt() only once like

```
$('#myGantt').gantt({
  data: myTask
  dtStart: '2019-05-05',
  dtEnd: '2019-09-05', ....
...
});
```

Comment: I created all in one function like suggested but the error stays.

Comment: did you link gnatt chart lib into your page? is the URL for the lib correct?

Comment: I linked to: <script src="...../sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/easy-gantt.js" type="text/javascript"></script> as well as: moment-with-locales.min.js and jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js

Comment: is the path "...../sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/easy-gantt.js" reach to the easy-gantt.js? My guess is either path is not correct or some permission issues to read the JS file

Comment: I believe the .js file is reached because I also get an error on the easy-gantt.js file. --> let locale = (options.locale)? options.locale: 'pt-BR'; (error ; expected)